# Окно регистрации/авторизации на Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Окно регистрации. Проблема такая, что по нажатию на кнопку "Зарегистрироваться" вновь появляются строки с вводом логина, пароля, возможно ли как то это предотвратить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код не мой, прилагаю ниже

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pickle

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x600')
root.title('Войти в систему')

def registration():
    text = Label(text='Для входа в систему зарегистрируйтесь')
    text_log = Label(text='Введите Ваш логин')
    registr_login = Entry()
    text_password1 = Label(text='Введите Ваш пароль')
    registr_password1 = Entry()
    text_password2 = Label(text='Еще раз пароль:')
    registr_password2 = Entry(show='*')
    button_registr = Button(text='Зарегистрироваться', command=lambda: save())
    text.pack()
    text_log.pack()
    registr_login.pack()
    text_password1.pack()
    registr_password1.pack()
    text_password2.pack()
    registr_password2.pack()
    button_registr.pack()

    def save():
        login_pass_save = {}
        login_pass_save[registr_login.get()] = registr_password1.get()
        f = open('login.txt', 'ab')
        pickle.dump(login_pass_save, f)
        f.close()
        registration()
        login()

def login():
    text_log = Label(text='Теперь вы можете войти в систему.')
    text_enter_login = Label(text='Введите ваш логин: ')
    enter_login = Entry()
    text_enter_pass = Label(text='Введите ваш пароль: ')
    enter_password = Entry(show='*')
    button_enter = Button(text='Войти', command=lambda: log_pass())
    text_log.pack()
    text_enter_login.pack()
    enter_login.pack()
    text_enter_pass.pack()
    enter_password.pack()
    button_enter.pack()

    def log_pass():
        f = open('login.txt', 'rb')
        a = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()
        if enter_login.get() in a:
            if enter_password.get() == a[enter_login.get()]:
                messagebox.showinfo('Вы авторизовались', 'Вход выполнен')
            else:
                messagebox.showerror('Ошибка', 'Неверный логин или пароль')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Ошибка', 'Неверный логин или пароль')

registration()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Так они не появляются вновь, они просто не убираются. Т.е. вам надо отчищать свой root от ненужных виджетов. Для этого можно воспользоваться методом `destroy`, которая удаляет виджет.
Так можно отчистить весь скрин от всего:

```
for ele in root.winfo_children():
    ele.destroy()
```

Comment: сейчас затестирую работоспособность

Comment: Благодарю, удаляет окно, знакомлюсь постепенно с tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

В 33 строку ты написал "registration", тем самым вызывая регистрацию ещё раз

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/829706)